# why is my javascript not working with my php file

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my javascript code...but it's not running. Is there anything wrong with this code??
I put all the id name correctly. But it's still not working

```js
function updateForm(){
  var name = document.getElementById("name");
  var msg = document.getElementById("massage");
  var text = "Dear " + name +",\n"+msg;
  document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = text;
  }


function placeForm(form){
  if(document.getElementById("name").value == ""){
    alert("You have to write your name");
  }
  else if (document.getElementById("email").value == "") {
    alert("You have to put email name in email box..It can be fake email name");
  }
  else if (document.getElementById("targetemail").value == "") {
    alert("You have to write the target email");
  }
  else if (document.getElementById("massage").value=="") {
    alert("You have to write some message atleast!");
  }
  else {
    form.submit();
  }

}
```

Comment: What does the form look like? Please add the code. Is PHP throwing any errors?

Comment: What is not working? Why are you building a string with DOM elements? `name` is a DOM element, not a string.

Comment: how are these functions being called?

Comment: @J.Hasan some feedback would be nice.

Comment: *"not working with my php file"* - "what" PHP file? and can you define "not working" for us? what errors do you get and what does your console show you? there isn't enough code and information to support the question.

Comment: sorry i forgot to put .value... i have to put document.getElementById("name").value;

Comment: @J.Hasan so are you saying that is the answer to your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not referencing the value of the elements. You do it correctly in the validation checks. So add the `.value` and you will be able to build your string.

```
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var msg = document.getElementById("massage").value;
var text = "Dear " + name +",\n"+msg;
```

And if you want a line break to show up to the user, you will need to use `<br>` and not `\n`.

Comment: "Maybe" is not an answer

Comment: What? How comes you go from -2 downvotes to +2 upvotes? With a wrong answer? ANd just in few seconds?

Comment: @bub, I agree with you. I dont know why people assume this is the problem without asking for details (thats why there are comments). This might or might not solve their problem. Quite a risk taker, so thumbs up for that.

Comment: @epascarello a bad explanation is a bad answer. Dont you agree?

Comment: That is why there is an edit feature and you can help improve answers.